# how to compress Uri image to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, compression, bitmapimage

this code show me an error i want to add selected image save to database and retrive i follow this 2 tutorials http://nizaqatali.wordpress.com/2011/06/21/android-dialog-select-image-from-gallery/   and this  http://androidhub4you.blogspot.com/2012/09/hello-friends-today-i-am-going-to-share.html
but this problem is come  error message"The method compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat, int, ByteArrayOutputStream) is undefined for the type Uri"

```
         import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

 public class SQLiteDemoActivity extends Activity {



final int SELECT_PHOTO = 0;
 ArrayList<Contact> imageArry = new ArrayList<Contact>();
 ContactImageAdapter adapter;
 Button BrowseButton;
 DataBaseHandler db;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

 db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
//get image from drawable
//Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.facebook);


 BrowseButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BrowseButton);



  BrowseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
    // select a file
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);


 }
  });



 }

@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent      
imageReturnedIntent) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

switch(requestCode) {
case SELECT_PHOTO:
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
 Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();



 //convert bitmap to byte
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
/**
* CRUD Operations
* */
 //Inserting Contacts
Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
  db.addContact(new Contact("FaceBook", imageInByte));
 //display main List view bcard and contact name

 //Reading all contacts from database
  List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
 for (Contact cn : contacts) {
  String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Name: " + cn.getName()
+ " ,Image: " + cn.getImage();

//Writing Contacts to log
Log.d("Result: ", log);
 //add contacts data in arrayList
imageArry.add(cn);

}
adapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this, R.layout.screen_list,
 imageArry);
ListView dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
 dataList.setAdapter(adapter);



}
}
}




}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use this code hope it help you

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();

InputStream imageStream = null;
try {
    imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
            selectedImage);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
try {
    stream.close();
    stream = null;
} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.

```
try {

url = new URL("Image URL");
InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```