# Compress image from Uri

Tags: java, android, image-compression

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageUri = result.getUri();
            storageReference.putFile(imageUri);
        }
    }
}
```

How to compress image from `Uri`? I don't want to compress it to `Bitmap` or store on device and retrieve from there. Is there any other way?

Comment: As we know, Uri refers to a resource. In addition, there is no way to compress an image without bringing it to the memory. So you should bring the image to memory, do a compression task and save it to storage. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859769/how-to-compress-uri-image-to-bitmap

Comment: Thank you, @aminography